# No me cambia el valor de un elemento creado dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Inyecto dinamicamente con `JQuery` un `td` con la `class` *totale* dentro de un `tr` con la `class` *princ* con el texto `'00'.`

`$("#ejemplo").append("<tr class='princ'> <td class='totale'>00</td></tr>");`

Después le quiero cambiar el valor y ponerle 'ejemplo':

`$("tr.princ .totale").text("ejemplo");`

No me lo cambia y no sé porque.

Comment: No creo, lo siento

Comment: Para que editas totalmente tu pregunta anterior y la vuelves a crear? así no funciona el sitio, creo que necesitamos la intervención de un moderador.

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código completo, no sabemos que está pasando, así como lo pones, debería funcionar, pero algo estarás haciendo mal.

Comment: Por favor Adrian elimina esta pregunta, en tu pregunta anterior ya tienes una respuesta que funciona y debería resolver tu problema, si tienes una nueva pregunta entonces creala, saludos!

Comment: @BenderPaisa me responde a la pregunta pero no la resuelve :)

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta anterior y agrega mas código como por ejm el html, con la información que das poco o nada se puede hacer lo importante es que elimines este duplicado innecesario

Answer (score 1):

Realiza esta prueba, agrege un span al td para que puedas acceder al valor que agregar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#ejemplo").append("<tr class='princ'> <td class='totale'><span id='spanCambia'>00</span></td></tr>");

});

$("#botonPrueba").click(function() {
     var valorCombio = "Ejemplo";
    $("#spanCambia").text(valorCombio);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="botonPrueba" value="Click me" (click)="modificarValor()">

<table>
   <tbody id="ejemplo">
   
   </tbody>
</table>
```

suponiendo que necesites cambir los valores por clases

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#ejemplo").append("<tr class='princ'> <td class='totale'>00</td></tr>");

});

$("#botonPrueba").click(function() {
     var valorCombio = "Ejemplo";
    $("tr.princ td.totale").text(valorCombio);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> Columna </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="ejemplo">
  
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" id="botonPrueba" value="Cambiar valor" (click)="modificarValor()">
```

solo haz esto, lo único que hice es crear una variable para asignarla

Comment: Te sirvió la solución ? o aun no resuelve tu duda ??

Comment: No del todo, pondría el html pero es muy complicado. Si lo acabo resolviendo comparto la solución.

Comment: De todas formas, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Pero entonces que es lo que quieres hacer , por que según la pregunta eso es lo que necesitas, o en que momento quieres que se cambie el valor ? cuando lances un evento  ?